# TG2.1: Proper location to store a database session instance?

Tags: mongodb, turbogears, pymongo

I am using a custom database (MongoDB) with TG 2.1 and i am wondering where the proper place to store the PyMongo connection/database instances would be?

Eg, at the moment they are getting created inside of my inherited instance of AppConfig. Is there a standard location to store this? Would shoving the variables into the `project.model.__init__` be the best location, given that under SQLAlchemy, the database seems to commonly be retrieved via:

```
from project.model import DBSession, metadata
```

Anyway, just curious what the best practice is.

Answer (score 0):

As of TurboGears 2.1.3, MongoDB support is integrated via the Ming ORM. I would look at a quickstarted project using the --ming option to get best practices if you want to do some customization: http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Ming.html